# multiple mysqli prepare statement in loop doesn't work

Tags: php, mysqli

this is my code where i have problem, here i am not getting any result for stmt2 fetch data,

```
$result = $user_hash_conn->query($q1);
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $stmt = $store_conn->prepare('SELECT `location`,`institute`, `category`, `sub_category`, `date`,`title`, `message` FROM `pre_demand_by_key` WHERE `key`=?');
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$key);

        # for no of match found 
        $stmt2 =  $store_conn->stmt_init();
        $stmt2 = $store_conn->prepare('SELECT `key` FROM `store_list` WHERE `location`=? AND `institute` LIKE ? AND `category`=? AND `sub_category` LIKE ?');



        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

            $key = $row['varchar_128'];

            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->bind_result($location,$institute,$category,$sub_category,$date,$title,$message);

            while($stmt->fetch()){

                #no of match found 
                $location2 = $location;
                $institute2 = $institute."%";
                $category2 = $category;
                $sub_category2 = $sub_category."%";

                $stmt2->bind_param("ssss",$location2,$institute2,$category2,$sub_category2);

                $stmt2->execute();
                $stmt2->bind_result($item_key2);
                echo $stmt2->error;
                $item_keys = [];
                while($stmt2->fetch()){
                    echo $item_key2;
                }



            }

        }

    }
```

i have record in my table for my second stmt, but here i doesn't give my any result all my code is correctly written(mean i didn't have spelling mistake related to db or tb name), when i manually check it on phpmyadmin it responsed with some result. Please help me. i am struggling with my code for last 4-5 hours

Comment: do you get a result for `$stmt` - or do you get into the 2nd `while($stmt->fetch())` and get values for `$location`,..?

Comment: Try to move `$stmt2->bind_param(...)` outside both loops (right after `$stmt2 = $store_conn->prepare`).  Binding params should only be done once, and setting bound params can be done in the loop. You also have to declare the params before binding of course.

Comment: @Jeff yes I get result of $stmt...

Comment: @Scamtex earlier I placed $stmt->bind_param just below prepare but it doesn't work, then placed it just before execute ()

Comment: If `$location2`, `$institute2`, `$category2` and `$sub_category2` really do hold values, this should work I believe. Are you absolutely sure the second query with those values yield in a match in the table? I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: @Scamtex, I have checked ( by echo )many times all this variables holds values, and second query works manually when I do on phpmyadmim